# Java heap memory allocation limits

Tags: java, memory

I've written the following test to check maximum available heap memory:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Memory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long maxMB = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1048576L;
        System.out.println("Maximum memory is " + maxMB + " MB.");
        ArrayList<byte[]> allocated = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            while (true)
                allocated.add(new byte[1024*1024]);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.out.println("allocated " + allocated.size() + " MB before running out of memory.");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I test this, it appears that only half of the "available" memory can actually be allocated:

```
$ java -Xmx512m Memory 
Maximum memory is 512 MB.
allocated 255 MB before running out of memory.
$ java -Xmx1024m Memory 
Maximum memory is 1024 MB.
allocated 511 MB before running out of memory.
```

Anyone know why this would be the case?

Comment: Maybe because the jvm can't find a continuous chunk of memory for your array?

Comment: I don't know why. But I did some tests, adding 100Kb at a time, or 10Mb at a time, and then using the Memory Analysis tool (MAT), I found that the amount of memory that was actually allocated increased(100Kb =>95% use ratio, 10Mb => 80% use ratio).   I think @JustanotherJavaprogrammer has a point.  And also I replaced the ```ArrayList``` with the ```LinkedList``` and got the same result.

Comment: @zysaaa weird about the linkedlist. That definitely not have that need.

Comment: You might be onto something there @JustanotherJavaprogrammer. When I make the chunk size small enough, it more or less uses up the whole memory. Still strange though that the memory manager would perform so poorly.

Comment: It kind of makes sense: the memory manager in Java is optimized for objects, which tend to be on the small side. There are a few bigger arrays for buffers and such, but they tend to be the minority (or allocated early on). Your example of allocating almost exclusively "big-ish" arrays is probably very untypical. Other applications that have needs for many array-ish buffers tend to use native memory. Probably because of this reason.

Comment: Which jvm and garbage collector have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what happens is that the memory manager tries to align the chunks at the next available 1MB boundary. But as the 1MB arrays actually take up slightly more than 1MB (for storing length and something else), they get arranged with a gap of almost 1MB between them. When reducing the block size by 16 bytes, they suddenly use up the whole memory again.